# Updating rows in Google Sheets using Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following Google Sheet with a tab called `db`:

[image]

In reality, the list is much longer. Eventually, I want to have a function triggered every hour to download data for 50 companies from Yahoo! Finance, as to not get rate restricted.

I am currently developing this function, and have the following in `Code.gs`:

```
function trigger() {
  var db =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('db'); 
  var tickers = db.getRange('A2:A').getValues();

  for (var row = 1; row <= 5; row++) { 
    console.log(tickers[row])
    var data = yahoo(tickers[row]);
    db.getRange(row, 2, 1, 3).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

I have been messing around with different starting values for `row`, but just do not get the result as expected. Instead I get:

[image]

How can I:

- not overwrite the cells in `B1, C1, D1` but have the data be inserted **behind** the respective tickers?
- run the loop not 5 times (as is now hardcoded), but only as many times as there are tickers? I tried `row <= tickers.length()` but got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) method, keep in mind that the number 1 corresponds to row 1, so if you want to no ovewrite the headers, you must initialize it at 2.

It is also important to mention, that the method you are using is highly inefficient, since you are calling the service every time the loop iterates. If you are going to make this script call every hour, you may [exceed the quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). So I recommend that you use [`setValues(values)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

Here is some pseudo-code that may help you.

```js
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

function fillWithoutLoops() {
  const tickers = sS.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat().filter(n => n)
  const tickersParsed = tickers.map(yahoo)
  sS
    .getRange(2, 1, tickersParsed.length, tickersParsed[0].length)
    .setValues(tickersParsed)
}

function yahoo(ticker) {
  return [ticker, "SOME", "DATA", "MORE"]
}
```

##### Documentation

- [Use batch operation(Best practices in Google Apps Script)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

Comment: Thanks! I find this difficult to inderstand (how it works exactly), will read up.

Comment: The main pints are: 1. Extract the values and filter it to have an array like `["BLK","AAPL", ...]`, 2. Pass this array to a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, there is where your fetch logic should be 3. Get a range that matches the dimensions of the new array, we get the `numRows` via `tickersParsed.length` and the `numColumns` via `tickersParsed[0].length` 4. Finally we set the values via setValues

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function trigger() {
  var db = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('db');
  var tickers = db.getRange('A2:A' + db.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();

  for (var row = 0; row < tickers.length; row++) {
    console.log(tickers[row])
    var data = yahoo(tickers[row]);
    db.getRange(row + 2, 2, 1, 3).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

explanation: the index of an array (tickers) starts at 0, not 1, so, as we catch the tickers of line 2, you must add 2 to get the corresponding ticker.